# Absolute positioned image in Relative div is breaking page layout

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

I have an image with `position:absolute;right-300px;` inside a container with `position:relative;` as I want the image to come out of the div and off to the right.

You can see it working [here](http://labs.ciaranhanrahan.com/test/). It's the first large image on the right.

The problem I have, is this is breaking the overall page layout and causing a vacant white space to the right of my page that can be side scrolled to.

If I put `overflow:hidden;` on the container div it will hide the rest of the image and I need the image to come out and be entirely visible.

Anyone have any suggestions for a way around this?

I tried writing up an example but I putting the whole page up seemed better
http://ciaranhanrahan.com/test/

Cheers!

Comment: I can't see what you're referring to on that page.

Comment: OK sorry - its the first large image you see on the right. Its a browser and phone and its 300px off to the right of a 960px grid.

Comment: Put `overflow:hidden` not on the immediate parent, but on your `header` element. (Or just `overflow-x`, if you don’t want to make it as high as necessary to display the image without being cut off in that direction.)

Comment: Similar question is here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411362/image-in-absolute-div-is-not-positioning-from-containing-div?rq=1

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - `overflow:hidden` on the <header> causes the image to be chopped off at the bottom though

Answer (score 0):

> I want the image to come out of the div and off to the right

Studying your page layout, it appears the image doesn't need to be in the `<div>` at all.

You could give the `<img />` a `position:absolute;`.

Then, you can include the `<img />` markup anywhere in your HTML source.

For instance, it's a 495kB image (ie. quite heavy) so you can include the absolutely positioned `<img />` at the very end of your HTML source, which means for first-time visitors to your page, the page will appear to load more quickly.

You won't need to nest the absolutely positioned `<img />` inside a parent element - which means you won't need to mess around with negative positioning, CSS inheritance, hiding overflow and so on.

Comment: Hi Rounin, so I see your point about taking it out of the parent element. But I still need it to sit off to the right of a 960 grid. I cant position it `absolute` `right:0;` as that would cause it to be way too far right on large screens so. I've updated the link to show you it as you suggested I think.

Comment: Can you deploy `position: absolute; left:972px;` instead?